# How can you prepopulate a field based on another field's value?

Tags: 8, webforms

this one was easy in Drupal 7. I defined a condition "If field A has value B, then field X will automatically get value Y".

How can I get this working for a Drupal 8 webform?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request for a third-party module hosted on drupal.org where this should be added as an issue. You also find the requested information in this screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic4wu-iZd4Y

Comment: OK. The screencast does not answer my question.

Comment: agree with Bert. that screencast is only covering how to make fields Visible if a specific option in a prior Element is chosen. it is not any help for how to set the value for the conditional Element

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the module maintainer will send you here if you enter a support question - he will **not** answer it in the issue queue.